# Is it possible to pass a script to YAML variable?

Tags: bash, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to work with gitlab's CI and it involves a YAML config file. Is it possible to pass a shell script to a variable?

something like:

```
TEST_VARIABLE: ./script.sh
```

The scripts is making a request to an api which will then output a string. If it's not possible, are there any workarounds?

Comment: The word "variable" is only used once in the [YAML spec](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) and that is as part of a scalar in example 2.28 ( part of something looking like an error message). What do you mean by "passing a script to YAML variable" as there are no such things as variables in YAML?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation refers to "[Expansion mechanisms - Execution shell environment](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#execution-shell-environment)"

> This is an expansion that takes place during the script execution. How it works depends on the used shell (bash/sh/cmd/PowerShell).
>
> For example, if the job’s script contains a line `echo $MY_VARIABLE-${MY_VARIABLE_2}`, it should be properly handled by bash/sh (leaving empty strings or some values depending whether the variables were defined or not), but will not work with Windows’ cmd/PowerShell, since these shells are using a different variables syntax.

On Linux, you could define `TEST_VARIABLE` in the [job script](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#script) as

```
export TEST_VARIABLE=$(/path/to/script.sh)
```